# Mocking Java Constant variables (public static) using Mockito/JUnit

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I need to mock the constant variable in order to test one of my method. How can I do it with Mokito and Junit.

```
  @Component( "mybean" )
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope( value="session" )  
  public class MyBean {

    Public void methodToBeTested() {
       if (!AppConst.SOME_CONST.equals(obj.getCostCode())) {
         // some logic
       }
    }
 }
```

AppConst class

```
@Configuration
public class AppConst
{
   public static  String  SOME_CONST;
   public static  String  HOST_URL;

   @PostConstruct
   public void postConstruct()
   {
     SOME_CONST = "My Code";
     HOST_URL  = "Some URL";

   }
}
```

So, from my junit test class, how can I mock the AppConst and it's variables? Now, when I run it, i hit a nullpointer error.

Can this be done with powermock? if yes please give some sample

Mockito version I use.

`compile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
compile "org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.1"`

Comment: If you think you need to mock those, you're definitely modeling things wrong. You should be injecting those values into your `MyBean` constructor (and in modern Spring, you should be configuring them via `@ConfigurationProperties`).

Comment: @chrylis  why need to inject it? It's a static variable which can access by through name.

Comment: As @chrylis said: To make it testable ;-)

Comment: Because *static state* makes your code a nightmare to deal with; they introduce hidden coupling. Constants are fine, and pure functions are fine. Not static state.

Comment: you mean in order to make junit success, I have to change the source code?

Comment: He means that static declaration is something you need to avoid in source code. When something is testable means its well written. If you have a trouble to test something it smells that something is going wrong

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis  what are the other options available if not to use static Constants?

Comment: External configuration which spring provides. You declare those variables in something like `application.yml` and create the a class in your project that will hold on those. Then you inject this class wherever you want to use them. Have a look at this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html and let me know if you want any clarifications

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis  these are not application varibales. These are constants that use such as `DEALER_CODE`,  `PAYMENT_MODE`, `SALES_CHANNEL`  Is it the way that move these constants also to the YML ?

Comment: Yes you can move everything you like in the application yml. And you can have a structure of something like : application.yml ( which is the default ) for all the constants and nothing specific to a customer, application-customer-profile.yml which will have all the constants and variables PER customer. So when you run your application you can choose which profiles to load and in which order ( except the default that load always and first)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking there would be another solution to be able to test it:

```
public void methodToBeTested(SomeObject obj) {
   performLogic(AppConst.SOME_CONST, obj);
}

boolean performLogic(String check, SomeObject testObj) {
   if (!check.equals(obj.getCostCode())) {
     // some logic
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

That way you can test two things, both combined show you that your code works as intended:

```
public void testMethodToBeTested() {
    MyBean mb = new MyBean() {
        @Override
        void performLogic(String check, SomeObject testObj) {
            assertSame("check constant is passed", AppConst.SOME_CONST, check);
        }
    }
    mb.methodToBeTested(new SomeObject());

    mb = new MyBean();
    SomeObject so = createSomeTestObject("My Code"); // not the actual constant but an equal String
    assertFalse("check some logic not occurred", mb.performLogic("My Code", so));
    so = createSomeTestObject("Not the constant");
    assertFalse("check some logic not occurred", mb.performLogic("Not the constant", so));
    assertTrue("check some logic occurred", mb.performLogic("My Code", so));
    // additional tests covering the actual logic
}
```

Another solution could be putting the condition of the if-statement into its own method, e.g. `shouldLogicOccurr(String check)` and test that method individually.

In other words: Sometimes it's necessary to refactor your code to make tests easier or sometimes even possible at all. A good side effect is the next time you implement something you already have testability in mind and create your code suitable for this in the first place.

Mocking is a good way to get things under test that use third party libraries that can't be changed and have too many dependencies to be set up but if you end up using that for your own code you've got a design issue.